# What is the time complexity for this nested for loop?

Tags: time, time-complexity, big-o, nested-for-loop

What would be the time complexity for the code below?
My guess is O(n log(n)) or O(n log(log(n))), but really not sure.
Would appreciate any help!

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
     for (int j = 1; j < log (n); j *= 2) {
          cout << '-';
     }
}
```

Comment: Talk us through your reasoning. How did you arrive at those guesses?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

it is clear that the first loop will run in

> O(n)

the inner loop can be calculated as follows if look at log(n) (the stop condition of the loop) as k then it'll look like this

```
for(int j = 0; j < k; j *= 2)
```

the runtime of this for loop is

> O(logk)

if we replace back log(n) instead of k we get the following

> O(log(logn))

hence this is an inner loop we need to multiply its runtime with the outer loop runtime.

> O(n) * O(log(logn)) => O(nlog(logn)).

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/practice-questions-time-complexity-analysis/) you can read more about loops runtime and how to analyze it.